# Is it more performant to have un-minified style in the HEAD or minified style in an external file?

Tags: html, css, performance, stylesheet, head

I like the idea of encapsulating my CSS into separate files. This also brings the added advantage of being able to easily minify the CSS. But I know performance is negatively impacted by the overhead needed to pull these separate files from the server.

To address the latter point, people often suggest inlining the style or at least putting the CSS in the HEAD of the html document. I'm not going to inline because then editing the style becomes a nightmare. I can consider putting it in the head to increase performance, but I do not want to put it in there minified. I won't be able to read it, and it will be a pain to have to adjust the CSS once minified.

So my question is, What is the better option -- in terms of performance -- between these two?

1. Minified external CSS file
2. CSS placed in the HEAD but not minified

Comment: The cost of extra HTTP hits to get files far outweighs having a few extra bytes of data to transfer, but putting the css in the document head is ugly and means you'll need some way of automatically including the style data in every page of your site. A single css file (potentially composed of several concatenated minified files) is a good compromise between separation of style (css) and content (html), and performance. You'll get far bigger performance gains from optimising images, enabling server compression, and removing extraneous javascript than you will from minification.

Answer (score 1):

You are not considering browser-side caching in your evaluation.  It is almost ALWAYS better to serve up CSS in an external file for cases where you will be using the same CSS file throughout a multi-page website.  The reason for this is that once the CSS is downloaded on first page visit, assuming you have expiry headers set properly, the browser will not need to download the CSS on subsequent page loads until the expiry TTL is passed.  This even holds true across multiple user sessions on a website, such that if a user visits the sites some days/weeks later, they may not need to download the CSS at all. If you served up in-page CSS, it would need to be downloaded on every page load.

Also minifying is typically not that big of a performance boost, as most server to browser connections will perform text compression on transmitted content anyway.

Of course it is also usually much easier to maintain CSS in an external file as you have pointed out.

Comment: What you're saying makes good sense. I'm just trying to understand why Google is barking at me about my CSS: http://imgur.com/PEo0Dud

Comment: @Doug Take what Google says with a pinch of optimisation salt; there is always a trade off between maximal optimisation and what is sensible to implement. A simple optimisation you could do there would be to concatenate those resources into a single file.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to:

1. Minify them all and bundle them in the server side with something like [bundles](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) for Asp.Net or [brewer](https://github.com/matehat/brewer.js) for nodejs, that way you remove the overhead you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment:

Generally, when optimising web page loading, you want to minimise the number of HTTP requests that the browser makes as these are expensive, time-wise; even requests for small files require the browser to send its request to a server, wait for the response, and then act accordingly. From that perspective, the best thing would be to put all the code for your page into a single file. However, this would be a page maintenance nightmare, and it also fails to take into account caching of resources by browsers, as covered by @MikeBrant.

A single css file (potentially composed of several concatenated minified files) is a good compromise between separation of style (css) and content (html), and performance. The same applies to javascript. You can also consider using a content delivery network (CDN) for Javascript if you're using a common library like JQuery as the user's browser may already have the library cached from visiting another site. Google's CDN serves a number of useful libraries.

Generally, you'll get far bigger performance gains from optimising images, enabling server compression, and removing extraneous javascript than you will from minification or inlining CSS. Images are almost always the "heaviest" elements of a page, and it is often very easy to reduce image size by 20-50% and maintain decent quality.